# react-native, pass params to DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Actually i have this drawerNavigator

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {...
    CreditsPage: { screen: CreditsPage },       
    TermsOfUsePage: { screen: TermsOfUsePage },
    LegalNoticePage: { screen: LegalNoticePage },        
  },
  {...}
);
```

`CreditsPage`, `TermsOfUsePage`, `LegalNoticePage` components just displays a webView , so only the source url change. `StaticWebView` is a component i created to factorise the `webView` code but i have to copy past the following code inside multiples files, no clean. I change only the config in each file

```
const config = {
  title: "Credits",
  icon: "copyright",
  url: "https://mysite.fr/credits"
}
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import IconFeather from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import StaticWebView from "project/src/page/StaticWebView.js"
import I18n from 'project/src/i18n/i18n';

export default class test extends React.PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: I18n.t(config.title),
      headerLeft: <View style={{ padding: 10, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <IconFeather name="arrow-left" size={25} color='black'
          onPress={() => { navigation.goBack(); navigation.navigate("DrawerToggle"); }} />
      </View>,
      drawerLabel: I18n.t(config.title),
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={config.icon} size={20} color={tintColor} />
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <StaticWebView url={config.url} />
    )
  }
}
```

I cannot find any how to pass parameters to drawerNavigator. For example like this :

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {...
    CreditsPage: { screen: staticWebView , config:{ url :"...."} },       
    TermsOfUsePage: { screen: staticWebView , config:{ url :"...."} }, 
    LegalNoticePage: { screen: staticWebView , config:{ url :"...."} },      
  },
  {...}
);
```

any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to Drawernavigator using `props` like below

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {...
    CreditsPage: { screen: props => <StaticWebView {...props} url="...." /> },
    TermsOfUsePage: { screen: props => <StaticWebView {...props} url="...." /> },
    LegalNoticePage: { screen: props => <StaticWebView {...props} url="...." /> },      
  },
  {...}
);
```

And you can access the props in StaticWebView component as below

```
const URL = this.props.url;
```

Comment: this don't work sorry. when i log `this.props` or `navigation` i get : 

`{state  : { key:"id-1518786806870-2" , params:undefined, routeName:"CreditsPage" } }`